# can't restart activity started by PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, launchmode

I can't restart one activity started by `PendingIntent`.

"can't restart" means nothing, for example, **onCreate** or **onNewIntent** is **never called** when `startActivity()` about activity already running.

the Activity named MainActivity I cant restart is  **singleTop** and overrides **onNewIntent**.

Here is manifest about `MainActivity`:

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

First, the `MainActivity` is started by notification with pending intent.

My PendingIntent is:

```
Intent iS = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
iS.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendindIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, iS, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And `MainActivity` execute `startService()`,and the service execute `sendBroadcast()`,
And the BroadcastClass execute `startActivity(Intent(this,MainActivity.class))`

Jere is the  BroadcastClass:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);

    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Then `onNewIntent()` is...not called ever `onCreate()`.

But when the program is started by pushing icon at homeScreen, `onNewIntent` in `MainActivity` is called by this same flow.

**Edit:** onNewIntent is here.

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {  
   Log.d("onNewIntent","onNewIntent");
   String SOMETHING = intent.getStringExtra("SOMETHING");

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll2);
    ll.removeAllViews();
    TextView textview1 = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.textview, null);

    textview1.setText(SOMETHING);
    ll.addView(textview1);
}
```

"onNewIntent" doesn't appear on LogCat.

Comment: Could you post your onNewIntent code please?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [bug in Android](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17137). See [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4155) also.

The problem is that the code in Android that decides whether or not to call `onNewIntent()` is using the flags in the `Intent` and not checking the flags in the manifest.

You should be able to fix this by adding `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` when starting the activity from the broadcast receiver, like this:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

It would also help if you would star and comment the issues on google code. If we make enough noise this might get fixed before 2020 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I encountered this problem after restarting only. It would be great to know why. 
To make my `PendingIntent`s work after restart I added the following flags on the `Intent` itself:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

And `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` for the `PendingIntent`. This behavior was quite odd since the pending intents work with no problems until the device restarts.